# Ajax call does not trigger Zend 2 EVENT_DISPATCH event

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

In my application module, I have an event listener, it fires on every page. Taken from Module.php in Application module:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'authenticate'),1);
}
public function authenticate(){ 
    //auth here. This works on every page load except an ajax call
}
```

Javascript:

```
var adminData={ ... }
return $.post("/admin/save",adminData); //Will not trigger EVENT_DISPATCH!
```

I have verified that the event triggers on every page load, except when called with javascript (ajax). If I browse to the link that the js calls (/admin/save), the event will fire. Why would the event not trigger when called with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to attach your listener with a higher priority so it will be triggered earlier. The action itself is also an event listener (`onDispatch` in the `AbstractActionController`) and is attached at priority 1 (see the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html#zend-mvc-mvc-event-dispatch-listeners)).
Try attaching your listener at priority 2:

```
$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'authenticate'),2);
```

Comment: Success! That did it. The event method is being called before the action code. But now I'm getting a different error, i'm trying to use the forward plugin and am seeing:
Forward plugin requires a controller that implements InjectApplicationEventInterface
Is this because the controller isn't instantiated yet?

Comment: Good question, I haven't used the forward plugin that much and I'm not sure if you can use it outside the controller. Maybe it's a better idea to redirect to you login page (looks like this is your use case)

Comment: How do you redirect from the module? I tried:

$controller=$e->getTarget();
return $controller->redirect()->toRoute("login");

Comment: Does [this](http://4zend.com/zend-framework-2-module-predispatch-and-redirect-2/) help?

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out the event is firing correctly on every dispatch, even ajax requests. What confused me though is that the code in the action method will execute first, and then the code in the method in the event trigger. So I had an error in my action code, that was dependent on the method the event should kick off. What would be teh event to listen on to execute a method **BEFORE** the action method code?